# jQuery function with window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

I'm trying to use other JavaScript/jQuery for several width. To start easily, I want to do 20% when window width > 981 and 100% when < 981. Here's my script that I've made out of other scripts.

```
<script>
if ($(window).width() < 981){
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "20%";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "20%";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
}
else ($(window).width() > 981){
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.display = "none";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

My HTML

```
<html>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a id="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <p> OVER MEZELF </p>
    <a href="/about/about.html">ABOUT</a>
    <p> PHP OPDRACHTEN </p>
    <a href="/bmi/bmi1.html">BEREKEN BMI</a>
    <a href="/array/array.html">ARRAY OPDRACHTEN</a>
    <p style="display:none;"> DOWNLOAD </p>
    <a href="download.zip" style="display:none;">DOWNLOAD ZIP BESTAND</a>
    <div id="date" style="color:#818181;font-size:15px;cursor:context-menu;font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase;margin-top:100%;"> <?php $today = date("F j, Y"); echo $today; ?></div>
    <div id="time" style="color:#818181;font-size:15px;cursor:context-menu;font-weight:bold;"></div>
</div>


<div id="main1">
    <span id="menu0" style="color:white;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
</div>
</html>
```

So when window < 981 show 100%, when > 981 show 20%. But this code isn't working. I hope someone knows.

(Sorry it's Dutch)

Comment: I think you need to learn about [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: I understand what you're meaning @mherzig , but that isn't the case. I know about window sizes in CSS and i'm already using that, but I don't think I can change that in the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem...

```
<script>
if ($(window).width() > 981){
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "20%";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "20%";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
}
else if ($(window).width() < 981){
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.display = "none";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Together with this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
</script>
```

And it worked... Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of the else if in Javascript

```
if (time < 10) {
    greeting = "Good morning";
} else if (time < 20) {
    greeting = "Good day";
} else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
}
```

so correct your code to

```
if ($(window).width() < 981){
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "20%";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "20%";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 981){
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "100%";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't worked for me. I can't even open the button openNav(). Maybe you know another solution. Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: did that rn @Jose Rojas

Comment: Maybe you can help me further. Thanks anyways. @Jose Rojas

Comment: The jsfiddle is working with code that you posted, maybe if you tell me what exactly is not working, I can help you @S.Brilleman

Comment: So the thing is: I have a nav opening from the left-side of the screen when i'm pushing ' onclick="openNav()" '. Then, the nav is going to the right 20%. But when I checked the mobile version ' @media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:980px) { ' it was 20% as well, and that is tiny. So i wanted to have a nav opening 100% when ' window-width < 980 '. You can also check it on the site http://s1100885.hbo-almere.nl (it's one of my first so it's ugly).

Answer (score 0):

Your functions should be declared outside the `if/else` block and use a var to communicate. You forgot the `else IF` too

```
<script>
    var openWidth = "100%";
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = openWidth;
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = openWidth;
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 981){
        openWidth = "20%";

    } else if ($(window).width() > 981){
        openWidth = "100%";
    }
</script>
```

It can be done by CSS too using [@media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Here you can set the width of open */
}
```

Comment: It is kinda working... but when I write 'var openWidth = "100%";' it looks like it will be always 100%. I changed it to 20% and is was always 20%. So it isn't working for me. Maybe you can help me further. Thanks anyways! @driconmax

Answer (score 0):

If this is all of the code, then there are a couple of issues that I can see.

1. You have `if` and `else` but that last one needs to be `else if`. But that presents another problem--if `width < 981`, else if `width > 981`, but what if the width is exactly 981? You are better off just removing `($(window).width() > 981)` and making it a normal `else` statement versus adding the `if`.
2. When does the width check run? Unless you are running that code on the resize event (and don't do that!) it will run once. So the opened size will be set *only* on page load. If you resize the browser after that, and move beyond the 981px threshold, you won't have the result you want.

So why do I say use media queries? First of all, let's look at the JS, and make the open/close functions very generic:

```
function openNav() {
    $("html").addClass("navopen");
}
function closeNav() {
    $("html").removeClass("navopen");
}
```

We are now essentially setting a state for the page, saying that the nav is opened or closed. So now the CSS:

```
#mySidenav {
    width: 0;
}

#main1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}

html.navopen #mySidenav {
    width: 100%;
}

html.navopen #main1 {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 981px) {
    html.navopen #mySidenav {
        width: 20%;
    }

    html.navopen #main1 {
        margin-left: 20%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Now, you can just use a simple toggle in JS to set if the nav is open, and use CSS for the rest. Easier to deal with, and you also don't have to set up handlers to see if the browser viewport size changes.

Comment: I tried and I know what you're code is for but when I try, there is no sidenav anymore. I copied it but it isn't working as wel ;'( . I'm still thanking you for trying and helping. http://s1100885.hbo-almere.nl